# Mapping drive through ssh tunnel between Windows computers?

Tags: windows-7, networking, cygwin, putty, ssh-tunnel

I have a Windows 7 computer that I use to acquire data and I want to be able to map it's C drive (or a folder in C and it's subfolders) in another Windows PC (using windows 8 now) to access it in windows explorer, over the internet (not LAN).

I'm trying to tunnel a ssh connection and followed the instructions on these sites: http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/CifsOverSSH/Win8Loopback.html http://www.leedberg.com/2005/03/secure-windows-file-sharing-over.html

First I tried to install freeSSHd but when I used puTTy to connect, it always returned "connection rejected". When I found the second link above, I installed Cygwin instead in the host and now I can use puTTy to ssh to it. I can even use WinSCP and get the files (in LAN).

I just need help to give the "last" step. I tried the instructions in the first link but when I try to access \10.255.255.1, I get the same problem as before, it says "connection rejected". Some other pages said to tunnel the port 139 also, but i'm not familiar with these configurations and what could be the problem. I think the problem is in the server Computer and not in the client.

I'm always missing some small little details, so every little tip may solve my problem,

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to forward port 139 on your router to the loopback adapter on your server. The problem is though that using the ip address you specified i'm guessing is different from the LAN. This will cause your router not to know where to send the packet. I would change the ip address of the loopback to one that is accessible to the router. Something like `192.168.0.200`

*Keep in mind that this is no longer a loopback since should be able to accept connections from outside your host machine.

You will then need to attempt the ssh connection to your public ip address, (visit whatismyip.com to find out), not the ip address you setup for the loopback adapter. You may also need to forward port 22(ssh) as well.

Comment: I shared my wi-fi connection (so the client pc acted like a gateway) with a cable conencted to the host and the connection worked. I couldn't try with my router, but i suppose the answer was something like you said.